# Exporting Plotly charts with Kaleido not working?

Tags: python, charts, plotly, plotly-python

I have locally created plotly charts in Jupyter Notebook that I'm trying to save as png files on my local machine.
Example of charts:

```
for table in EG_SD_pivots:
    df = EG_SD_pivots[table].reset_index()
    fig = make_subplots(specs=[[{"secondary_y": True}]])

    fig.add_trace(
            go.Scatter(x=df.iloc[:, 0], y=df['SD_Credibility'], name="Credibility", marker=dict(color=yellow)), secondary_y=True)

    fig.add_trace(
            go.Bar(x=df.iloc[:, 0], y=df['EG_LR_Rel'], name="EG Relativity", marker=dict(color=teal)), secondary_y=False)

    fig.add_trace(
            go.Bar(x=df.iloc[: ,0], y=df['SD_LR_Rel'], name="SD Relativity", marker=dict(color=indigo)), secondary_y=False)

    # Add figure title
    fig.update_layout(title_text=df.iloc[:0].columns[0], margin=dict(b=200))

    # Set x-axis title
    fig.update_xaxes(title_text=df.iloc[:0].columns[0])

    fig.update_yaxes(title_text="<b>Relativity</b>", secondary_y=False)
    fig.update_yaxes(title_text="<b>Credibility</b>", secondary_y=True)
    fig.show()
```

I've tried a number of different solutions, but they've all returned various errors...
Solutions:
`fig.to_image(format="png")` --> returns

```
ValueError: 
The orca executable is required to export figures as static images,
but it could not be found on the system path.
```

`plotly.orca.config.executable = 'C:/Program Files/Anaconda3/pkgs/plotly-4.0.0-py_0/site-packages/plotly/io/_orca.py'` --> returns

```
AttributeError: module 'chart_studio.plotly' has no attribute 'orca'
```

`plotly.offline.iplot(fig, filename=(str(chart) + '.png'))` --> returns

```
AttributeError: module 'chart_studio.plotly' has no attribute 'offline'
```

`fig.write_image("EG_SD_images/" + str(chart) + ".png", engine="kaleido")` --> returns

```
`TypeError: write_image() got an unexpected keyword argument 'engine'`
```

`plotly.image.save_as(fig, filename=(str(chart) + '.png'))` --> returns

```
Error                                     Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\contrib\pyopenssl.py in wrap_socket(self, sock, server_side, do_handshake_on_connect, suppress_ragged_eofs, server_hostname)
    452             try:
--> 453                 cnx.do_handshake()
    454             except OpenSSL.SSL.WantReadError:

C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\OpenSSL\SSL.py in do_handshake(self)
   1906         result = _lib.SSL_do_handshake(self._ssl)
-> 1907         self._raise_ssl_error(self._ssl, result)
   1908 

C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\OpenSSL\SSL.py in _raise_ssl_error(self, ssl, result)
   1638         else:
-> 1639             _raise_current_error()
   1640 

C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\OpenSSL\_util.py in exception_from_error_queue(exception_type)
     53 
---> 54     raise exception_type(errors)
     55 

Error: [('SSL routines', 'tls_process_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')]

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

SSLError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py in urlopen(self, method, url, body, headers, retries, redirect, assert_same_host, timeout, pool_timeout, release_conn, chunked, body_pos, **response_kw)
    599                                                   body=body, headers=headers,
--> 600                                                   chunked=chunked)
    601 

C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py in _make_request(self, conn, method, url, timeout, chunked, **httplib_request_kw)
    342         try:
--> 343             self._validate_conn(conn)
    344         except (SocketTimeout, BaseSSLError) as e:

C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py in _validate_conn(self, conn)
    838         if not getattr(conn, 'sock', None):  # AppEngine might not have  `.sock`
--> 839             conn.connect()
    840 

C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connection.py in connect(self)
    343             server_hostname=server_hostname,
--> 344             ssl_context=context)
    345 

C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\ssl_.py in ssl_wrap_socket(sock, keyfile, certfile, cert_reqs, ca_certs, server_hostname, ssl_version, ciphers, ssl_context, ca_cert_dir)
    343         if HAS_SNI and server_hostname is not None:
--> 344             return context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=server_hostname)
    345 

C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\contrib\pyopenssl.py in wrap_socket(self, sock, server_side, do_handshake_on_connect, suppress_ragged_eofs, server_hostname)
    458             except OpenSSL.SSL.Error as e:
--> 459                 raise ssl.SSLError('bad handshake: %r' % e)
    460             break

SSLError: ("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'tls_process_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')])",)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

MaxRetryError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py in send(self, request, stream, timeout, verify, cert, proxies)
    448                     retries=self.max_retries,
--> 449                     timeout=timeout
    450                 )

C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\connectionpool.py in urlopen(self, method, url, body, headers, retries, redirect, assert_same_host, timeout, pool_timeout, release_conn, chunked, body_pos, **response_kw)
    637             retries = retries.increment(method, url, error=e, _pool=self,
--> 638                                         _stacktrace=sys.exc_info()[2])
    639             retries.sleep()

C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\urllib3\util\retry.py in increment(self, method, url, response, error, _pool, _stacktrace)
    397         if new_retry.is_exhausted():
--> 398             raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
    399 

MaxRetryError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.plotly.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /v2/images (Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'tls_process_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')])")))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

SSLError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\chart_studio\api\v2\utils.py in request(method, url, **kwargs)
    171     try:
--> 172         response = requests.request(method, url, **kwargs)
    173     except RequestException as e:

C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\api.py in request(method, url, **kwargs)
     59     with sessions.Session() as session:
---> 60         return session.request(method=method, url=url, **kwargs)
     61 

C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py in request(self, method, url, params, data, headers, cookies, files, auth, timeout, allow_redirects, proxies, hooks, stream, verify, cert, json)
    532         send_kwargs.update(settings)
--> 533         resp = self.send(prep, **send_kwargs)
    534 

C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\sessions.py in send(self, request, **kwargs)
    645         # Send the request
--> 646         r = adapter.send(request, **kwargs)
    647 

C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\requests\adapters.py in send(self, request, stream, timeout, verify, cert, proxies)
    513                 # This branch is for urllib3 v1.22 and later.
--> 514                 raise SSLError(e, request=request)
    515 

SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.plotly.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /v2/images (Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'tls_process_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')])")))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

PlotlyRequestError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-39-fb5a62f7ab75> in <module>
     69     fig.show()
     70     EG_SD_charts[table] = fig
---> 71     plotly.image.save_as(fig, filename=(str(chart) + '.png'))
     72     #plotly.offline.iplot(fig, filename=(str(chart) + '.png'))
     73     #fig.write_image("EG_SD_images/" + str(chart) + ".png", engine="kaleido")

C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\chart_studio\plotly\plotly.py in save_as(cls, figure_or_data, filename, format, width, height, scale)
    908             filename += "." + format
    909 
--> 910         img = cls.get(figure_or_data, format, width, height, scale)
    911 
    912         f = open(filename, "wb")

C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\chart_studio\plotly\plotly.py in get(figure_or_data, format, width, height, scale)
    817             payload["scale"] = scale
    818 
--> 819         response = v2.images.create(payload)
    820 
    821         headers = response.headers

C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\chart_studio\api\v2\images.py in create(body)
     16     """
     17     url = build_url(RESOURCE)
---> 18     return request("post", url, json=body)

C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\retrying.py in wrapped_f(*args, **kw)
     47             @six.wraps(f)
     48             def wrapped_f(*args, **kw):
---> 49                 return Retrying(*dargs, **dkw).call(f, *args, **kw)
     50 
     51             return wrapped_f

C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\retrying.py in call(self, fn, *args, **kwargs)
    204 
    205             if not self.should_reject(attempt):
--> 206                 return attempt.get(self._wrap_exception)
    207 
    208             delay_since_first_attempt_ms = int(round(time.time() * 1000)) - start_time

C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\retrying.py in get(self, wrap_exception)
    245                 raise RetryError(self)
    246             else:
--> 247                 six.reraise(self.value[0], self.value[1], self.value[2])
    248         else:
    249             return self.value

C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\six.py in reraise(tp, value, tb)
    691             if value.__traceback__ is not tb:
    692                 raise value.with_traceback(tb)
--> 693             raise value
    694         finally:
    695             value = None

C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\retrying.py in call(self, fn, *args, **kwargs)
    198         while True:
    199             try:
--> 200                 attempt = Attempt(fn(*args, **kwargs), attempt_number, False)
    201             except:
    202                 tb = sys.exc_info()

C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\chart_studio\api\v2\utils.py in request(method, url, **kwargs)
    177         status_code = response.status_code if response else None
    178         content = response.content if response else "No content"
--> 179         raise exceptions.PlotlyRequestError(message, status_code, content)
    180     validate_response(response)
    181     return response

PlotlyRequestError: No message
```

Comment: Have you tried `fig.to_image(format="png", engine="kaleido")` ?

Comment: Yes, that returns the same error as fig.write_image("EG_SD_images/" + str(chart) + ".png", engine="kaleido") -- TypeError: to_image() got an unexpected keyword argument 'engine'

Comment: After installation of https://anaconda.org/conda-forge/plotly-orca through "conda install ...." the worked. 

I do not know why, but it works. If someone knows why plotly does not already includes the above, please reply here.

Answer (score 7):

I also had the error: `TypeError: write_image() got an unexpected keyword argument 'engine'.` According to [plotly/Kaleido manual](https://github.com/plotly/Kaleido):

> *Versions 4.9 and above of the Plotly Python library will automatically use Kaleido for static image export when Kaleido is installed.*

**Try to check the version by:**

```
import plotly
plotly.__version__
```

**You can then update your Plotly by:**

```
pip install plotly==5.3.1
```

This will uninstall the old version and install the recent one.

Comment: Thank you. This worked perfectly. Though I had a Plotly version 5.5.0, I do not know why it did not work. But after instaling 5.3.1, `pip install plotly==5.3.1` everything worked nicely.

Comment: I have the same problem, the pip or conda install siccessfully and the ploty also downgrade to 5.3.1, still doesnt work.

Comment: Downgrading from 5.5.0 to 5.3.1 worked for me as well.

Comment: Note: after installing `plotly==5.3.1`, remember to restart your kernel and then import plotly again. This helped me.

Answer (score 0):

Personnaly, I use the GUI directy.

[image]

Comment: But I have a very large image and the resolution is very low if I save through the GUI.