# How to create a rotating animation of a Scatter3D plot with plotly and save it as gif?

Tags: python, animation, 3d, plotly, jupyter

With plotly in jupyter I am creating a Scatter3D plot as follows:

```
# Configure the trace.
trace = go.Scatter3d(
    x=x,
    y=y,
    z=z,
    mode='markers',
    marker=dict(color=colors, size=1)
)

# Configure the layout.
layout = go.Layout(
    margin={'l': 0, 'r': 0, 'b': 0, 't': 0},
    height = 1000,
    width = 1000
)

data = [trace]

plot_figure = go.Figure(data=data, layout=layout)

# Render the plot.
plotly.offline.iplot(plot_figure)
```

How can I rotate a plot generated like this in order to create a gif video out of it i.e. stored as a gif file like `rotate.gif` which shows an animation of the plot rotated?

Based on the comments given I created this code (complete, working example):

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np
import plotly.io as pio


# Helix equation
t = np.linspace(0, 10, 50)
x, y, z = np.cos(t), np.sin(t), t

fig= go.Figure(go.Scatter3d(x=x, y=y, z=z, mode='markers'))

x_eye = -1.25
y_eye = 2
z_eye = 0.5

fig.update_layout(
         title='Animation Test',
         width=600,
         height=600,
         scene_camera_eye=dict(x=x_eye, y=y_eye, z=z_eye),
         updatemenus=[dict(type='buttons',
                  showactive=False,
                  y=1,
                  x=0.8,
                  xanchor='left',
                  yanchor='bottom',
                  pad=dict(t=45, r=10),
                  buttons=[dict(label='Play',
                                 method='animate',
                                 args=[None, dict(frame=dict(duration=5, redraw=True), 
                                                             transition=dict(duration=1),
                                                             fromcurrent=True,
                                                             mode='immediate'
                                                            )]
                                            )
                                      ]
                              )
                        ]
)


def rotate_z(x, y, z, theta):
    w = x+1j*y
    return np.real(np.exp(1j*theta)*w), np.imag(np.exp(1j*theta)*w), z

frames=[]
for k, t in enumerate(np.arange(0, 6.26, 0.1)):
    xe, ye, ze = rotate_z(x_eye, y_eye, z_eye, -t)
    newframe = go.Frame(layout=dict(scene_camera_eye=dict(x=xe, y=ye, z=ze)))
    frames.append(newframe)
    pio.write_image(newframe, f"images/images_{k+1:03d}.png", width=400, height=400, scale=1)
fig.frames=frames

fig.show()
```

which runs without an error and does rotate the scenery when I press on Play, however the image that is saved just shows an empty 2D coordinate system:

[image]

but not what I actually see rotating. It also seems those image are created when I execute the cell in the jupyter notebook and not after I press "Play". Seems that there are two figures, one that I can see rotating, and the image of an empty 2D coordinate system that gets saved to a file ...

Comment: Making the frames for a gif is discussed [here](https://community.plotly.com/t/how-to-export-animation-and-save-it-in-a-video-format-like-mp4-mpeg-or/64621/2). And rotation is included here](https://community.plotly.com/t/rotating-3d-plots-with-plotly/34776/2).

Comment: I'd make your naming scheme simpler. I worry the f-string is complicating how it is grabbing the `.png` part, see [here](https://github.com/plotly/Kaleido/issues/131#issuecomment-1082652642). (That was for old plotly stuff but the ideas may be pertinent?) It may be as simple as forming the name on a separate line. Worth a try. Or did you try updating Kaleido? See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69016568/8508004). OR add specifying the format with something like `format="png"`, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67374558/8508004).

Comment: @Wayne Tried to put something together but without much success, see complete (non)working code in question ...

Comment: Could you separate out your **UPDATE** section better? Maybe just a heading like `### Update based on initial comments`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note [`pio.write_image()`](https://plotly.github.io/plotly.py-docs/generated/plotly.io.write_image.html) expects a Figure object or dict representing a figure as the 1st argument (we can't just pass an update object or a frame). The idea is precisely to *apply* the changes from each animation frame to the figure and export it at each point sequentially :

```py
frames=[]
for k, t in enumerate(np.arange(0, 6.26, 0.1)):
    xe, ye, ze = rotate_z(x_eye, y_eye, z_eye, -t)
    newframe = go.Frame(layout=dict(scene_camera_eye=dict(x=xe, y=ye, z=ze)))
    frames.append(newframe)
    fig.update_layout(scene_camera_eye=dict(x=xe, y=ye, z=ze))
    pio.write_image(fig, f"images/images_{k+1:03d}.png", width=400, height=400, scale=1)
```

The animation frames describe only the changes to be applied at some point to the figure, asynchronously, using Plotly.js `animate` method (js runtime), but the image export *is* done synchronously (python runtime), before the figure is eventually rendered (because before `fig.show()`).

Answer (score 0):

This below is closer. We need to work on the size and zoom though, I suspect.

```py
import plotly.graph_objects as go
import numpy as np
import plotly.io as pio

# Helix equation
t = np.linspace(0, 10, 50)
x, y, z = np.cos(t), np.sin(t), t

fig= go.Figure(go.Scatter3d(x=x, y=y, z=z, mode='markers'))

x_eye = -1.25
y_eye = 2
z_eye = 0.5

fig.update_layout(
         title='Animation Test',
         width=600,
         height=600,
         scene_camera_eye=dict(x=x_eye, y=y_eye, z=z_eye),
         updatemenus=[dict(type='buttons',
                  showactive=False,
                  y=1,
                  x=0.8,
                  xanchor='left',
                  yanchor='bottom',
                  pad=dict(t=45, r=10),
                  buttons=[dict(label='Play',
                                 method='animate',
                                 args=[None, dict(frame=dict(duration=5, redraw=True), 
                                                             transition=dict(duration=0),
                                                             fromcurrent=True,
                                                             mode='immediate'
                                                            )]
                                            )
                                      ]
                              )
                        ]
)


def rotate_z(x, y, z, theta):
    w = x+1j*y
    return np.real(np.exp(1j*theta)*w), np.imag(np.exp(1j*theta)*w), z

frames=[]
for k,t in enumerate(np.arange(0, 1.26, 0.1)):
    xe, ye, ze = rotate_z(x_eye, y_eye, z_eye, -t)
    frames.append(go.Frame(layout=dict(scene_camera_eye=dict(x=xe, y=ye, z=ze))))
    current_fig = go.Figure(fig.data, layout=dict(scene_camera_eye=dict(x=xe, y=ye, z=ze)))
    pio.write_image(current_fig, f"images/images_{k+1:03d}.png", width=400, height=400, scale=1)
fig.frames=frames

fig.show()
```

##### Explanation:

In your updated code, it looks like you were taking [this code](https://community.plotly.com/t/rotating-3d-plots-with-plotly/34776/2) and attempting to add in the saving of the figure based on the use of `pio.write_image()` that I pointed out [here](https://community.plotly.com/t/how-to-export-animation-and-save-it-in-a-video-format-like-mp4-mpeg-or/64621/2). (I don't really see the purpose of the `Play` button for your case, other than it allows you to sort of check things work in development like this. It may though be cluttering animation you actually want to share ultimately.)
However, you weren't quite collecting what you wanted for the frames you were sending to `.png` files.

With the following:

```py
newframe = go.Frame(layout=dict(scene_camera_eye=dict(x=xe, y=ye, z=ze)))
frames.append(newframe)
pio.write_image(newframe, f"images/images_{k+1:03d}.png", width=400, height=400, scale=1)
```

You were sending a frame object to `pio.write_image`. I think you want the figure though with the original data and so you needed to reconstruct that using something similar to what is covered in [this reply to this Plotly issue 'Getting frames of animations'](https://github.com/plotly/plotly.py/issues/2046#issuecomment-572597122).

So now I changed the code to use the layout you use for the frame but make a figure using that and the original data.